# Is it possible to break on next event in IE10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

I'm working on a project that I haven't been with since the beginning so I don't know the code base very well yet. There seems to be an event on a textbox that runs on blur but I can't find it in the code at all. I'm hoping that IE has the debugger feature where it can break when a particular type of event has been triggered (in my case, the next blur to happen). Or is there a way to get a list of events on an input control?

Comment: Hoping that IE has any kind of feature is futile, use a proper browser and you can probably set proper breakpoints and figure out where the event handler is.

Comment: I wish I could. It's to my understanding that Active Directory and similar Domain info doesn't work in Chrome. Please, PLEASE, correct me if I'm wrong. I would love to be wrong about that.

Comment: This is for a work intranet project. I don't get much wiggle room on requirements.

Comment: @adeneo Internet Explorer 10 is capable of doing precisely what you're instructing Corey to go to another browser for. Corey, if you know which method is being raised, you can set a breakpoint within it and start debugging. If you're using jQuery, you can access all bound handlers via `$._data`.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I have no clue what method is being called, that's the issue. I am using jQuery though so maybe that'll shed some light. I didn't know about `$._data`

Comment: You can call `$._data( el, "blur" )` where `el` is a reference to your element which is being blurred. Note, this needs to be a reference to the element itself, and not a jQuery collection containing the element.

Comment: The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus. Onblur is most often used with form validation code (e.g. when the user leaves a form field). The onblur event is the opposite of the onfocus event. What is the behavior that is triggering this event?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Within the Script tab in your F12 Developer Tools there is a Break All option (Ctrl+Shift+B), which will pause immediately before the next script execution. This may be what you're looking for.

Comment: If you can't find a `blur` handler maybe it is actually a `change` handler?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn You can find all events bound to the input by simply leaving off the event in `$.data`. For instance, to find every event handled for `document`, we'd do this: `$.data(document)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I found it (thanks to @JonathanSampson's `$.data` hint) as a change event. Now I have enough to go on.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I did not however find a Break All option or get the hotkey Ctrl+Shift+B to work. That is what I was originally hoping for. Do you know of a non-hotkey way to find it? Note: I did find "Break on all exceptions" but no exception is occuring in my scenario.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn The feature is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx#_control If this doesn't help, I can get on my PC and assist further.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Ok, clicking the pause button will do that. Misunderstood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pause script execution in Internet Explorer 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_control)'s Developer Tools. This will cause the execution to stop immediately just before the next script is ran. You can then step through execution to target the logic you're hunting for.

Alternatively, if you're binding events with jQuery you can tap into `$._data` and identify all of the bound events for any given element. For instance, suppose we had an input element that was behaving oddly, we could determine all bound events like this:

```
// We need a reference to the element, not a jQuery collection
var firstname = $("#firstname")[0];

// Next we pass the element as a reference
console.log( $._data( firstname ) );
```

This returns the full data object for that particular element. On this resulting object will be an events collection showing all events handled, as well as the handlers ran when those events are raised.

Hope this helps.